# Importing a method from user-defined module gives Attribute Error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, attributeerror

I am going through python crash course book and i want to import a module that i have written its function and saved it properly in the path.
using pycharm, python 3.7

I have properly written the code and i know it exists(the attribute) in the imported module.

the code is this:

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings):
"""Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
   print(f"\nMaking a {size}-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
   for topping in toppings:
      print(f"- {topping}")
```

but i get this error `AttributeError: module 'pizza' has no attribute 'make_pizza'`

*I dont know what to do,i really need to solve this problem to be able to continue my learning.*

[image: Here is what i do to import it .]

Comment: Show us the code raising this error, meaning, the **importing** code as well

Comment: That `make_pizza()` is a method, but you mention it as attribute ? Do you import it as a function or attribute ?

Comment: sorry @amrs-tech i meant method.

Comment: Try checking the package with `print(dir(pizza))`

Comment: check out again sir @Tomerikoo

Comment: @amrs-tech,as function not attribute. i checked it out `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'pizza']
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'pizza']`

Comment: you are doing `import pizza` in the `pizza.py` file. You are importing the file you are in. In what file is your `make_pizza` function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your module and then check for the directory structure, if it is like,

```
|-pizza/
|--pizza.py
```

Then try this for importing pizza module in another python program:

```
from pizza import pizza
pizza.make_pizza(10,...)
```

I hope this helps. This maybe because of your package structure.

Comment: thanks it worked,really appreciate it .now i can import and see the out put i want . thank you.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer, so that it might be helpful for others too.